# jQuery toggle - Icons switch on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to create a jQuery toggle Play & Pause icons, I want to toggle the icons onClick.

**Note:**

My demo is code working fine but I'm looking for a feature like...If I clicked on the first **Play Icon** and it will change. When I click on second **Play Icon** it will change with **Pause Icon** then the first **Pause Icon** will change with **Play Icon** and It will repeat with the third icon.

**Demo Code:**

```js
$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
$("#infoToggler2").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
$("#infoToggler3").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infoToggler"><img src="http://c28.imgup.net/play-icon223d.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>
<img src="http://e52.imgup.net/stop-icon731e.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
</div>

<div id="infoToggler2"><img src="http://c28.imgup.net/play-icon223d.png
" width="60px" height="60px"/>
<img src="http://e52.imgup.net/stop-icon731e.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
</div>

<div id="infoToggler3"><img src="http://c28.imgup.net/play-icon223d.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>
<img src="http://e52.imgup.net/stop-icon731e.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

I found these links on Stack Overflow but they're not what I'm looking for.

[jQuery Toggle on click of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348458/jquery-toggle-on-click-of-image)

[How to jQuery toggle multiple images on different button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081034/how-to-jquery-toggle-multiple-images-on-different-button-click)

Comment: I'm sorry im unclear abt ur question

Comment: Which anchor links?

Comment: The code you provided seems to work..

Comment: @Adjit But if you do `Run code snippet` and click on the images, it works.

Comment: I have updated my question I'm using toggle with image not with anchor link.

Comment: @JacquesMarais you are correct... it seems like the OP's code is working.

Comment: @JacquesMarais, My code working I'm looking for feature like...If I clicked on first image it will change when I click on second image the first will change to normal stage it will repeat with third image .

Comment: @SayedRafeeq Oh I see what you mean.

Comment: @JacquesMarais, I'm trying to achieve to that feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, work with classes rather than IDs, then you only need one handler, not multiple.  So, give the divs a class.

Next, give the 'reset' image one class and the other a different one.  This allows you to reset the others.

You can then add a handler to the div to toggle images in that div and reset all others:

```js
 $(".toggler").click(function() {
    
        // Reset all images
        $(".toggler img.alt").hide();
        $(".toggler img.orig").show();
        
        // Now toggle the ones in this .toggler
        $("img", this).toggle();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggler'>
        <img class='orig' src="http://c28.imgup.net/play-icon223d.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>
        <img class='alt'  src="http://e52.imgup.net/stop-icon731e.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
    </div>

    <div class='toggler'>
        <img class='orig' src="http://c28.imgup.net/play-icon223d.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>
        <img class='alt'  src="http://e52.imgup.net/stop-icon731e.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
    </div>

    <div class='toggler'>
        <img class='orig' src="http://c28.imgup.net/play-icon223d.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>
        <img class='alt'  src="http://e52.imgup.net/stop-icon731e.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Awesome, you have understand my problem also thanks for your explanation, I had checked your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sayedrafeeq/tq3Lvgxh/1/  ...it's brilliant. :)